# collapse dataframe based on rows and calculate weighted mean r

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate, bioinformatics

I would like to collapse the following dataframe

```
df

Chromosome  Start   End lengthMB    imba    log2    Cn  mCn Cn_
chr1    0   8022945 8.023   0.026905119 -0.001671481    2   1   1.99
chr1    8022945 9168284 1.145   0.030441784 0.000601976 2   1   2
chr1    9168284 9598904 0.431   NA  -0.024952441    2   1   1.91
chr1    9598904 31392788    21.794  0.036011994 0.002151497 3   1   3.01
chr2    0   8022930 8.023   0.026905119 -0.001671481    3   1   2.89
chr2    8022930 9168284 1.145   0.030441784 0.000601976 2   1   1.87
chr2    9168284 9598904 0.431   NA  -0.024952441    2   1   1.57
chr2    9598904 31392788    21.794  0.036011994 0.002151497 2   0   1.87
chr2    31392788    35402000    1.164   0.029733771 0.003149921 2   1   2.01
chr3    0   8040000 1.479   NA  0.000969256 2   1   2
chr3    8040000 9168284 8.185   0.033499045 -0.031338811    1   0   0.89
chr3    9168284 9598904 3.952   0.036792754 0.002847936 1   0   0.78
chr3    9598904 31392788    0.883   0.049003807 -0.021413391    2   1   1.92
chr3    31392788    35402000    4.095   0.037653564 0.011944688 2   1   2.04
chr4    0   8022930 11.065  0.035092332 -0.022844471    2   1   1.91
chr4    8022930 9168284 40.635  0.037690844 0.006703603 2   1   2.02
chr4    9168284 9598904 0.545   0.047435696 -0.021068024    2   1   1.92
```

By matching only consecutive rows that have the same Cn and mCn values I want to collapse the rows. For example for the first 4 rows, we have the following:

```
Chromosome  Start   End lengthMB    imba    log2    Cn  mCn Cn_
chr1    0   8022945 8.023   0.026905119 -0.001671481    2   1   1.99
chr1    8022945 9168284 1.145   0.030441784 0.000601976 2   1   2
chr1    9168284 9598904 0.431   NA  -0.024952441    2   1   1.91
chr1    9598904 31392788    21.794  0.036011994 0.002151497 3   1   3.01
```

I want to collapse consecutive rows where they have the same Cn and mCn score, so for the first three rows that each has a "2" and "1" on the Cn and mCn column respectively and also to change the End column to reflect this collapse.

```
Chromosome  Start   End lengthMB    imba    log2    Cn  mCn Cn_
chr1    0   9598904 8.023   0.026905119 -0.001671481    2   1   1.99
```

But I would also like to change the `Cn_column` so that it is the weighted average `Cn_dependant` on what the `lengthMB` score is for that row. So for the first three rows the calculation would be:

```
((8.023/9.599) * 1.99) + ((1.145/9.599) * 2) + ((0.431/9.599) * 1.91) = 1.987
```

output for the first four unique Chromosomes:

```
Chromosome  Start   End lengthMB    imba    log2    Cn  mCn Cn_
chr1    0   9598904 8.023   0.026905119 -0.001671481    2   1   1.99
chr1    9598904 31392788    21.794  0.036011994 0.002151497 3   1   3.01
chr2    0   8022930 8.023   0.026905119 -0.001671481    3   1   2.89
chr2    8022930 9598904 1.145   0.030441784 0.000601976 2   1   1.79
chr2    9598904 31392788    21.794  0.036011994 0.002151497 2   0   1.87
chr2    31392788    35402000    1.164   0.029733771 0.003149921 2   1   2.01
chr3    0   8040000 1.479   NA  0.000969256 2   1   2
chr3    8040000 9598904 8.185   0.033499045 -0.031338811    1   0   0.836
chr3    9598904 35402000    0.883   0.049003807 -0.021413391    2   1   2.02
chr4    0   9598904 11.065  0.035092332 -0.022844471    2   1   2
```

Tried something like this, but I also don't know how to include the calculation...

```
squish_segments <- function(sample) {
  setDT(sample)[, .ind:= cumsum(c(TRUE,Start[-1]!=End[-.N])),
    list(lengthMB, probes, snps, imba, log2, Cn, mCn, Cn_)][,
   list(Chr=Chromosome[1], Start=Start[1], End=End[.N]),
   list(lengthMB, probes, snps, imba, log2, Cn, mCn, Cn_, .ind)][,.ind:=NULL][]
}
```

Comment: How `((8.023/9.599) * 1.99) + ((1.145/9.599) * 2) + ((0.431/9.599) * 1.91) = 1.9435` ? I found `1.987601`. Also, when you collapse those rows what values do you want to keep for columns that contain different information? Eg. `Start`, `End`, `imba`, `log2`.

Comment: I want to keep all the columns

Comment: I know you want to keep them, but you don't specify what values you want to have. For example, `chr1` with `Cn = 2` and `mCn = 1` has 3 rows initially, so it has 3 different values in those columns. Also, in your desired output you have a chromosome with the same `Cn` and `mCn` multiple times. Check rows 4 and 6 for `chr2` and rows 7 and 9 for `chr3`. Looks like your not collapsing those for some reason.

Comment: yes, that is because I want to only collapse consecutive events, not just similar Cn and mCn unique events with the same Chromosome. That's why rows 4 and 6 and 7 and 9 aren't also being collapsed

Comment: Cool. I'll have a look at it soon.

Answer (score 1):

First, please make your questions more reproducible by providing the `dput` output of your dataset.

I think this is what you want at a low level.

```
setkey(df, Chromosome, Cn, mCn, Start)

df[, list(
  Start=min(Start), 
  End=max(End), 
  lengthMB=lengthMB[1], 
  imba=imba[1],
  log2=log2[1],
  Cn_=weighted.mean(Cn_, lengthMB) 
), keyby=list(Chromosome, Cn , mCn)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a `dplyr` approach.

```
library(dplyr)

df = read.table(text=
                  "Chromosome  Start   End lengthMB    imba    log2    Cn  mCn Cn_
                chr1    0   8022945 8.023   0.026905119 -0.001671481    2   1   1.99
                chr1    8022945 9168284 1.145   0.030441784 0.000601976 2   1   2
                chr1    9168284 9598904 0.431   NA  -0.024952441    2   1   1.91
                chr1    9598904 31392788    21.794  0.036011994 0.002151497 3   1   3.01
                chr2    0   8022930 8.023   0.026905119 -0.001671481    3   1   2.89
                chr2    8022930 9168284 1.145   0.030441784 0.000601976 2   1   1.87
                chr2    9168284 9598904 0.431   NA  -0.024952441    2   1   1.57
                chr2    9598904 31392788    21.794  0.036011994 0.002151497 2   0   1.87
                chr2    31392788    35402000    1.164   0.029733771 0.003149921 2   1   2.01
                chr3    0   8040000 1.479   NA  0.000969256 2   1   2
                chr3    8040000 9168284 8.185   0.033499045 -0.031338811    1   0   0.89
                chr3    9168284 9598904 3.952   0.036792754 0.002847936 1   0   0.78
                chr3    9598904 31392788    0.883   0.049003807 -0.021413391    2   1   1.92
                chr3    31392788    35402000    4.095   0.037653564 0.011944688 2   1   2.04
                chr4    0   8022930 11.065  0.035092332 -0.022844471    2   1   1.91
                chr4    8022930 9168284 40.635  0.037690844 0.006703603 2   1   2.02
                chr4    9168284 9598904 0.545   0.047435696 -0.021068024    2   1   1.92", header=T)


df %>%
mutate(Consec = ifelse(Chromosome == dplyr::lag(Chromosome, default = Chromosome[1]) &  ## flag consecutive matching chromosomes
                         Cn == dplyr::lag(Cn, default = Cn[1]) & 
                         mCn == dplyr::lag(mCn, default = mCn[1]), 0, 1),
       Consec = cumsum(Consec)) %>%       ## create an id for consecutive matching chromosomes
group_by(Chromosome, Cn, mCn, Consec) %>%
summarize(Cn_ = sum(lengthMB * Cn_)/sum(lengthMB),
            Start = min(Start),
            End = max(End),
            lengthMB = first(lengthMB),
            imba= first(imba),
            log2= first(log2)) %>%
ungroup() %>%    ## only if you want to ungroup
select(Chromosome,Start,End, lengthMB,imba,log2,Cn,mCn,Cn_) %>%  ## to re arrange column order
arrange(Chromosome, Start)


#    Chromosome    Start      End lengthMB       imba         log2    Cn   mCn       Cn_
#        (fctr)    (int)    (int)    (dbl)      (dbl)        (dbl) (int) (int)     (dbl)
# 1        chr1        0  9598904    8.023 0.02690512 -0.001671481     2     1 1.9876008
# 2        chr1  9598904 31392788   21.794 0.03601199  0.002151497     3     1 3.0100000
# 3        chr2        0  8022930    8.023 0.02690512 -0.001671481     3     1 2.8900000
# 4        chr2  8022930  9598904    1.145 0.03044178  0.000601976     2     1 1.7879569
# 5        chr2  9598904 31392788   21.794 0.03601199  0.002151497     2     0 1.8700000
# 6        chr2 31392788 35402000    1.164 0.02973377  0.003149921     2     1 2.0100000
# 7        chr3        0  8040000    1.479         NA  0.000969256     2     1 2.0000000
# 8        chr3  8040000  9598904    8.185 0.03349904 -0.031338811     1     0 0.8541823
# 9        chr3  9598904 35402000    0.883 0.04900381 -0.021413391     2     1 2.0187143
# 10       chr4        0  9598904   11.065 0.03509233 -0.022844471     2     1 1.9956599
```

Note that `lag` is a `dplyr` function, but also a `stats` package function. I have to write `dplyr::lag` otherwise there's a conflict when I try to specify `default =` within `lag`. I don't know if you or anyone else can replicate this issue.

Comment: Hey, I have included the output for the next two unique chromosome values as this isn't giving me quite the output I would like! thanks

Comment: I'll check again my process based on the new data you provided. But, no matter how hard I'll try I'll never make `((8.023/9.599) * 1.99) + ((1.145/9.599) * 2) + ((0.431/9.599) * 1.91)` equal to `1.9435`.

Answer (score 0):

Could identify unique "events" (consecutive rows with same Cn and mCn score) and then simply loop through those events and modify the rows accordingly. Not the most efficient but should do the job.

```
txt <- "Chromosome  Start   End lengthMB    imba    log2    Cn  mCn Cn_
chr1    8022945 9168284 1.145   0.030441784 0.000601976 2   1   2
chr1    9168284 9598904 0.431   NA  -0.024952441    2   1   1.91
chr1    9598904 31392788    21.794  0.036011994 0.002151497 3   1   3.01
chr2    0   8022930 8.023   0.026905119 -0.001671481    3   1   2.89
chr2    8022930 9168284 1.145   0.030441784 0.000601976 2   1   1.87
chr2    9168284 9598904 0.431   NA  -0.024952441    2   1   1.57
chr2    9598904 31392788    21.794  0.036011994 0.002151497 2   0   1.87
chr2    31392788    35402000    1.164   0.029733771 0.003149921 2   1   2.01
chr3    0   8040000 1.479   NA  0.000969256 2   1   2
chr3    8040000 9168284 8.185   0.033499045 -0.031338811    1   0   0.89
chr3    9168284 9598904 3.952   0.036792754 0.002847936 1   0   0.78
chr3    9598904 31392788    0.883   0.049003807 -0.021413391    2   1   1.92
chr3    31392788    35402000    4.095   0.037653564 0.011944688 2   1   2.04
chr4    0   8022930 11.065  0.035092332 -0.022844471    2   1   1.91
chr4    8022930 9168284 40.635  0.037690844 0.006703603 2   1   2.02
chr4    9168284 9598904 0.545   0.047435696 -0.021068024    2   1   1.92"

df <- read.table(text=txt, header=T)

#identify each unique event
df$eventid <- with(df, cumsum(c(1,diff(as.numeric(factor(Chromosome)))!=0 | diff(Cn)!=0 | diff(mCn)!=0)))

#loop through events
for(i in 1:max(df$eventid)){
    #identify rows in df with ith event
    rows.i <- which(df$eventid == i)

    df[rows.i,] <- within(df[rows.i,],{
        #calculate values of interest and assign to first row of event
        Start[1] <- min(Start)
        End[1] <- max(End)
        Cn_[1] <- sum((lengthMB/sum(lengthMB))*Cn_) 
        lengthMB[1] <- sum(lengthMB)    
    })

    #drop all but first row
    if(length(rows.i) > 1) df <- df[-rows.i[-1],]

} #end i
```

result

```
> df
   Chromosome    Start      End lengthMB       imba         log2 Cn mCn       Cn_ eventid
1        chr1  8022945  9598904    1.576 0.03044178  0.000601976  2   1 1.9753871       1
3        chr1  9598904 31392788   21.794 0.03601199  0.002151497  3   1 3.0100000       2
4        chr2        0  8022930    8.023 0.02690512 -0.001671481  3   1 2.8900000       3
5        chr2  8022930  9598904    1.576 0.03044178  0.000601976  2   1 1.7879569       4
7        chr2  9598904 31392788   21.794 0.03601199  0.002151497  2   0 1.8700000       5
8        chr2 31392788 35402000    1.164 0.02973377  0.003149921  2   1 2.0100000       6
9        chr3        0  8040000    1.479         NA  0.000969256  2   1 2.0000000       7
10       chr3  8040000  9598904   12.137 0.03349904 -0.031338811  1   0 0.8541823       8
12       chr3  9598904 35402000    4.978 0.04900381 -0.021413391  2   1 2.0187143       9
14       chr4        0  9598904   52.245 0.03509233 -0.022844471  2   1 1.9956599      10
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, you can do it in one line with `data.table` fast grouping.

```
library(data.table)
dt[, Cn_dependent := sum((lengthMB/sum(lengthMB)) * Cn_),
   by = .(Chromosome, Cn, mCn)]
```

to get this:

```
> dt
   Chromosome    Start      End lengthMB       imba         log2 Cn mCn  Cn_ Cn_dependent
1:       chr1        0  8022945    8.023 0.02690512 -0.001671481  2   1 1.99     1.987601
2:       chr1  8022945  9168284    1.145 0.03044178  0.000601976  2   1 2.00     1.987601
3:       chr1  9168284  9598904    0.431         NA -0.024952441  2   1 1.91     1.987601
4:       chr1  9598904 31392788   21.794 0.03601199  0.002151497  3   1 3.01     3.010000
5:       chr2        0  8022930    8.023 0.02690512 -0.001671481  3   1 2.89     2.890000
6:       chr2  8022930  9168284    1.145 0.03044178  0.000601976  2   1 1.87     1.882285
7:       chr2  9168284  9598904    0.431         NA -0.024952441  2   1 1.57     1.882285
8:       chr2  9598904 31392788   21.794 0.03601199  0.002151497  2   0 1.87     1.870000
9:       chr2 31392788 35402000    1.164 0.02973377  0.003149921  2   1 2.01     1.882285
```

To collapse by `Chromosome`, `Cn` and `mCn`, you could use keys and `unique`.

```
> setkey(dt, "Chromosome", "Cn", "mCn")
> unique(dt)
   Chromosome   Start      End lengthMB       imba         log2 Cn mCn  Cn_ Cn_dependent
1:       chr1       0  8022945    8.023 0.02690512 -0.001671481  2   1 1.99     1.987601
2:       chr1 9598904 31392788   21.794 0.03601199  0.002151497  3   1 3.01     3.010000
3:       chr2 9598904 31392788   21.794 0.03601199  0.002151497  2   0 1.87     1.870000
4:       chr2 8022930  9168284    1.145 0.03044178  0.000601976  2   1 1.87     1.882285
5:       chr2       0  8022930    8.023 0.02690512 -0.001671481  3   1 2.89     2.890000
```

Here is a `dput` of the `data.table` I started with:

```
> dput(dt)
structure(list(Chromosome = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("chr1", "chr2"), class = "factor"), Start = c(0L, 
8022945L, 9168284L, 9598904L, 0L, 8022930L, 9168284L, 9598904L, 
31392788L), End = c(8022945L, 9168284L, 9598904L, 31392788L, 
8022930L, 9168284L, 9598904L, 31392788L, 35402000L), lengthMB = c(8.023, 
1.145, 0.431, 21.794, 8.023, 1.145, 0.431, 21.794, 1.164), imba = c(0.026905119, 
0.030441784, NA, 0.036011994, 0.026905119, 0.030441784, NA, 0.036011994, 
0.029733771), log2 = c(-0.001671481, 0.000601976, -0.024952441, 
0.002151497, -0.001671481, 0.000601976, -0.024952441, 0.002151497, 
0.003149921), Cn = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), mCn = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Cn_ = c(1.99, 2, 1.91, 3.01, 
2.89, 1.87, 1.57, 1.87, 2.01)), .Names = c("Chromosome", "Start", 
"End", "lengthMB", "imba", "log2", "Cn", "mCn", "Cn_"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x26abf68>)
```